# Python rounding incorrect result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to round number in python but it keep giving me the inaccurate result
for example I want to round 99.999999946 into 99.99, or 56.3633333 into 56.36
this is what I've tried:

```
int(99.999999946*100)/100   #result = 99
int(99.999999946*100)/100.0 #result = 99.989999999999995
round(99.999999946, 2)      #result = 100.0
```

thanks before

Comment: Welcome to limited precision floating-point arithmetic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point is a good starting point.

Comment: 99.999999946 is closer to 100.0 than to 99.99

Comment: [Click this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for a writeup specifically for Python users.  Use the `decimal` module if you can't abide ;-) shallow surprises like this one.

Comment: it's a little confusing actually, will spent some time learning it, thanks for the reference guy :)

Comment: It is at times quite confusing, but still important for any numerical work :)

Answer (score 3):

Until you get comfortable with limitations of binary floating point, you'll probably be much happier with the `decimal` module, which implements a rich decimal floating-point model.  Among other things, it allows fine control over rounding modes:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d = decimal.Decimal("99.999999946")
>>> print d
99.999999946
>>> chopped = d.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".01"), decimal.ROUND_DOWN)
>>> print chopped
99.99
```

### Generalizing

Here's a function that will chop to any digit position you like, and returning a float too (which is, in general, inexact!):

```
def chop_to_n_decimals(x, n):
    # This "rounds towards 0".  The decimal module
    # offers many other rounding modes - see the docs.
    import decimal
    d = decimal.Decimal(repr(x))
    targetdigit = decimal.Decimal("1e%d" % -n)
    chopped = d.quantize(targetdigit, decimal.ROUND_DOWN)
    return float(chopped)
```

For example,

```
for x in 5555.5555, -5555.5555:
    for n in range(-3, 4):
        print x, n, "->", chop_to_n_decimals(x, n)
```

displays:

```
5555.5555 -3 -> 5000.0
5555.5555 -2 -> 5500.0
5555.5555 -1 -> 5550.0
5555.5555 0 -> 5555.0
5555.5555 1 -> 5555.5
5555.5555 2 -> 5555.55
5555.5555 3 -> 5555.555
-5555.5555 -3 -> -5000.0
-5555.5555 -2 -> -5500.0
-5555.5555 -1 -> -5550.0
-5555.5555 0 -> -5555.0
-5555.5555 1 -> -5555.5
-5555.5555 2 -> -5555.55
-5555.5555 3 -> -5555.555
```

Comment: so I must pass in a string of the float?
but when I tried str(99.99999999995695) I get '100.0' instead of '99.99999999995695'

Comment: You don't have to pass in a string.  But if you pass in a float, you'll get the *exact* decimal representation of that binary float - read the link I gave you in a comment for more on that.  Until you understand this stuff better, pass `repr(99.99999999995695)` instead of using `str`.

Comment: For example, `Decimal(0.1)` creates `Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')`.  And that result is explained in great detail in the link I already gave you.

Comment: thanks for the troubles Tim,
but when I tried repr(99.9999999999999999999958) it's giving me '100.0', :|

Comment: *There* you're attempting the impossible. Binary floats only have 53 bits of precision - the binary float created for the literal 99.9999999999999999999958 is *exactly* 100.0. Did you read the link I gave you? There are alternatives to thrashing blindly in the dark ;-) Again, the `decimal` module is what you *need* if you really need that many significant digits. You can set the precision of the decimal type to millions of digits (if you need to). You can't change *anything* about your hardware's binary floating point (which  is what the Python `float` type uses).

Answer (score 2):

All the results are correct. `int` rounds down, whereas `round` rounds to the nearest number (i.e. digits 0-4 get rounded down, 5-9 up for positive numbers). In Python 2.x, `/` with integer arguments is integer division unless you import `division` from `__future__`, and integer division rounds down as well.

`int(99.999999946*100)/100` gets evaluated as

```
int(99.999999946*100)/100
int(9999.9999946) / 100
9999 / 100 # int rounds down
99         # integer division rounds down
```

The division in `int(99.999999946*100)/100.0` is a float one. The result may not be precisely 99.98, but [that's to be expected](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info) since 0.98 = 48 / 50 cannot be expressed in base 2.

```
int(99.999999946*100)/100.0
int(9999.9999946) / 100.
9999 / 100.0        # int rounds down
99.989999999999995  # floating-point division
```

For your last example, note the digit at the second decimal place

```
round(99.999999946, 2) = 100.0
round(99.989999999999995, 2) = 99.99
```

If you want correct (but rather slow) *decimal* calculation, use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/decimal.html) module:

```
import decimal
d = decimal.Decimal('99.999999946')
d.quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'), decimal.DOWN)  # Decimal('99.99')
```

Comment: so I must pass in a string of the float?
but when I tried str(99.99999999995695) I get '100.0' instead of '99.99999999995695'

Comment: @Edxz The `decimal` module operates with strings, right. But you must give it the string literally. `99.99999999995695` is a floating-point constant, so you've already got a floating-point value. Simply use `'99.99999999995695'`. In general, if you want precise (money etc.) calculation, use decimal. If you want scientific simulations, use floating-point.

Comment: but it's not always 99.99999999995695, it can be some other value
so I can't directly use 'number' , is there any other solution ?thanks for the solutions :)

Comment: @Edxz How are you obtaining this number? You must go to the source of that number then, and require it to be a string. Note that you can also just use `decimal.Decimal(99.99999999995695)`. This will use the closest decimal value of the floating-point number, and in this case, will lead to a result of `99.99`. But if you need precise values, you should not use floating-point anywhere.

Comment: @phihag the problem isn't with floating point - `Decimal` is still a floating point type. But `float` is a *binary* floating point format, which is where the problems come in.

Comment: @phihag, `Decimal(a_float)` creates the *exact* decimal value of `a_float`, no matter how many decimal digits that requires.  A binary float can always be converted to an exact decimal float - the reverse is not always true (in fact, few decimal floats can be converted exactly to binary floats).

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to round to the desired number of decimal places.

```
def round_decimal(dec, places=2):
    return int((dec * 10**places) + 0.5) / 10.**places
```